# Filtering in pandas by index - Keyerror

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am trying to filter in Pandas for a selected period. (picture added) The start and the end date is to be entered in an input box.

"Day" is found in the index column, however the third line gives an error message.

```
df = pd.read_excel('prices.xlsx', index_col=0)
df.iloc[::-1]
filtered_date = df[(df['Day'] >= 'start_date') & (df['Day'] <= 'end_date')]
```

I get a "KeyError" message. I googled that key_error happens if a key is not available in a dictionary. I do not use a dictionary in my code, and I do not understand how to fix it. The key "Day" is indeed the first value of the first(index) row.

Thank you.

[This is my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufmiP.jpg)

Comment: `df['Day'] >= 'start_date'` why do you do this? start_date is a str .
Are you trying to compare the values ​​of the day column with a string?

Comment: I enter the value from an input box: 

date_entry = input('Enter the start date in YYYY-MM-DD format')
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
start_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)

I would like to filter a period between start and end date and get a new dataframe

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the picture of your DataFrame:

- All names of "regular" columns are located a bit higher.
- "Day" is located a bit lower and it indicates that it is the name of
  the **index** column.

Your code contains *df['Day']*, so you attempt to reference a **regular**
column named *Day*.
As regular column of this name does not exist, an exception is thrown.

There are 2 ways to cope with this:

1. Drop *index_col=0* from the call to *read_excel*. This way *Day* will
   be a **regular** column, so your following code should work.
2. Change *df['Day']* to *df.index*. This way you refer to the **index**.

Of course, put any valid date string instead of *start_date* and *end_date*.

And one more thing to consider: As *Day* is a matter of fact a column holding
**dates**, it should have *datetime* type. So probably you should add
*parse_dates=[0]* parameter to *read_excel*, to have this column converted from
*string* to *datetime*.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and providing me with a detailed answer. As I am a  beginner in Python/Pandas it helps me a lot.